# How to calculate ProgressBar percentage for daily drink water

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I made an app about android water drinking monitor. But it does the wrong calculation as a percentage. What do you think I might have done wrong. 
(When the progress bar is 100 at 100, the daily water calculation is wrong)

```
waterml = sharedPreferences.getInt(WATER_ML, 0);
waterdata = sharedPreferences.getInt(WATER_DATA, 0);
int dailywater = 2838; // example        
ml100.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //scale 100 ml
        int percent = 100  * 100 / dailywater;
        ProgressBarAnimation anim = new ProgressBarAnimation(circlebar, waterdata, (waterdata + percent));
        anim.setDuration(300);
        circlebar.startAnimation(anim);
        dailywater.setText((waterml + 100) + " / " + dailywater + " ml");
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(WATER_DATA, (waterdata + percent));
        editor.putInt(WATER_ML, (waterml + 100));
        editor.apply();
    }
});
////
public static class ProgressBarAnimation extends Animation {
    private CircleProgressBar progressBar;
    private float from;
    private float to;
    ProgressBarAnimation(CircleProgressBar progressBar, float from, float to) {
        super();
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        float value = from + (to - from) * interpolatedTime;
        progressBar.setProgress((int) value);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like your progress is not being saved correctly. Try to change `editor.apply();` to `editor.commit();` if it helps, i'll post a detailed answer

Comment: @IlyaMaier The problem is not saving the main problem is calculating the percentile incorrectly. Did you watch the video? https://yadi.sk/i/kcSGAbVDAtZs8Q

Comment: I saw the video. Your calculation is based on saving values to shared preferences, right? So you basically save the progress each time and then get it and add a new portion of progress?

Comment: Yes that's right.. `int percent = 100 * 100 / dailywater;` I think this is wrong

Comment: No it actually shouldn't be wrong... Did you change the line to `editor.commit();`? Just try it, and if it doesn't help, we'll continue to search.

Comment: I'm trying please wait

Comment: @IlyaMaier nothing changed .. I think it calculated incorrectly .. because, for example, daily water requirement (as in the example 2838 ml) 2838 ml when we divide this by 1000 ml, 2.838 results. but in the program this value is rounding to 30%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211931/discussion-between-ilya-maier-and-theoyuncu8).

Comment: @IlyaMaier Can you come back to the chat room? There is something I have to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like your code, namely `editor.apply();` is working as follows:

you are trying to save the progress and it occurs that sometimes it is called multiple times in a row. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply%28%29) if you are sending several `apply()` or `commit()` commands only the last one will be executed. Therefore, some clicks might not be processed.

I suggest you simply changing your variable for progress and saving it later:

```
waterml = sharedPreferences.getInt(WATER_ML, 0);
waterdata = sharedPreferences.getInt(WATER_DATA, 0);
int dailywater = 2838; // example        
ml100.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //scale 100 ml
        int percent = 100  * 100 / dailywater;
        ProgressBarAnimation anim = new ProgressBarAnimation(circlebar, waterdata, (waterdata + percent));
        anim.setDuration(300);
        circlebar.startAnimation(anim);
        dailywater.setText((waterml + 100) + " / " + dailywater + " ml");

        waterdata += percent;
        waterml += 100;
    }
});
```

and then in your `onPause()` function you simply save them:

```
public void onPause() {
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(WATER_DATA, waterdata);
    editor.putInt(WATER_ML, waterml);
    editor.apply();
}
```

If you want your percent not to be rounded, you could change `putInt` to `putFloat` and `getInt` to `getFloat`